# How to get child element inner text of xml?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file which contains...

```
<Addresses>
    <Address>
        <Plot>79/435</Plot>
        <Pin>
            <Pin>4</Pin>
        </Pin>
    </Address>
    <Address>
        <Plot>79/438</Plot>
        <Pin>
            <Pin>6</Pin>
        </Pin>
        <pin>
            <pin>19</pin>
        </pin>
    </Address>
    <Address>
        <Plot>79/439</Plot>
        <Pin>
            <Pin>9</Pin>
        </Pin>
        <Pin>
          <Pin>10</Pin>
        </Pin>
    </Address>
</Addresses>
```

In this xml each `<plot>` has unique `innerText` but the `<pin>` element value is single or multiple against each `<plot>`...How i can get the  `<plot>` and `<pin>` `innerText` by using c#...

Answer (score 0):

I would Suggest you to use `XmlSerializer` & `XmlDeserializer` so that your xml will be converted to class object and then you can use LINQ

Examples :

[XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part)

[XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/487571/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Link to XML to achieve this. It is fairly simple, please see the following MSDN documentation.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387053.aspx

Your code should look like below.

```
        XElement root = XElement.Load("YourXML.xml");
        var Plots =
            from el in root.Elements("Address")
            select new { Plot = el.Element("Plot").Value, Pins = el.Elements("Pin").Select( p => p.Element("Pin").Value ).ToList() };

        foreach (var p in Plots)
        {
            string tmpPolt = p.Plot;
            List<string> tmpPins = p.Pins;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this?

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlString);

        foreach (XmlElement node in doc.GetElementsByTagName("Pin"))
        {
            if( node.FirstChild.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After lots of try i found a solution of my own...

```
XmlDocument load = new XmlDocument();
load.LoadXml(xmlString);
XmlNode xNodeAddresses = load.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Addresses");
for (int i = 0; i < xNodeAddresses.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
{
        XmlNode xnodeAddress = xNodeAddresses.ChildNodes[i];
        string plot= xnodeAddress.FirstChild.InnerText;
        //do stuff with plot
        for (int j = 0; j < xnodeAddress.ChildNodes.Count; j++)
        {                                
                 if (j>0)
                 {
                       string pin = xnodeHolding.ChildNodes[j].FirstChild.InnerText;
                       //do stuff with pin                     
                 }
        }
}
```